# Best practice to show user data in PHP

Tags: php

This is my `USER` class for getting user data.

```
require_once "classes/DB.php";

class USER {

    private $session_user_id = 1;
    //$session_user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];

    private $user_data;
    public $username;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $profile_photo;

    private static $instance = null;

    //kthen objekt.
    private function __construct() {
        $db = DB::get_instance();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $this->session_user_id";
        $run_query = $db->mysqli->query($query);
        $this->user_data = $run_query->fetch_assoc();

        $this->username = $this->user_data["username"];
        $this->first_name = $this->user_data["first_name"];
        $this->last_name = $this->user_data["last_name"];
        $this->profile_photo = $this->user_data["profile"];
    }

    public static function get_instance() {
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }

        public function first_name() {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

}

$user = USER::get_instance();
```

Can anybody tell me which is the best method to make private `properties` and to get content using a public `get_name();` method like `echo $user->get_last_name()`?

or to just echo property content?  `echo $user->last_name`.

Extra question: how can I use `$_SESSION` variables inside a class? Should I pass it as a function parameter?

Comment: In response to the "extra" question: `$_SESSION` is a superglobal, so you can access it from inside a class. Whether or not you should depends on what you plan to use it for, however.

Comment: I prefer getter functions, since public properties are open to external code setting them with invalid values.

Comment: I find "best method" pretty use-case-specific. But, creating getters and setters allows more flexibility (i.e. access modifiers), and also the ability to create *only* a getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should view the popular framework designs for `$_SESSION` question.

In my opinion, it's better to use getter and setter methods for object-oriented approach. Because these variables cannot be modified from outside when compared with direct call of variables from class. Also, you can use protected variables are better than privates.

You can read these topics from Stack Overflow:

[Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

[What is the point of getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407877/what-is-the-point-of-getters-and-setters?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It would be great if you vote my post. Thanks again. @user3566301